# Android App crashing as i click button, issue with onClickListener

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm creating a simple android application and was moving along nicely until i created a new class and attempted to implement two buttons.

I simply cannot get my head around why they aren't working/initialising correctly.

Here is my code:

```
public class CreateSurveyActivity extends Activity {

EditText editQuestion, editAnswer1, editAnswer2, editAnswer3;
Button btnNext, btnComplete;
SurveyDataBaseAdapter SurveyDataBaseAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photoalbum);

    // get Instance  of Database Adapter
    SurveyDataBaseAdapter = new SurveyDataBaseAdapter(this);
    SurveyDataBaseAdapter = SurveyDataBaseAdapter.open();

    // Get References of Views
    editQuestion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextQuestion);
    editAnswer1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAnswer1);
    editAnswer2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAnswer2);
    editAnswer3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAnswer3);

    // Get Refs of buttons


    btnComplete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUP);
}


 public void createSurvey(){

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CreateSurveyActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.photoalbum);
    dialog.setTitle("Create");

    // get the Refferences of views
    final  EditText editQuestion=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextQuestion);
    final  EditText editAnswer1=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextAnswer1);
    final  EditText editAnswer2=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextAnswer2);
    final  EditText editAnswer3=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextAnswer3);

     // Set On ClickListener .... Error here i presume.
     btnNext = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
     btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String question = editQuestion.getText().toString();
            String answer1 = editAnswer1.getText().toString();
            String answer2 = editAnswer2.getText().toString();
            String answer3 = editAnswer3.getText().toString();

            // check if any of the fields are vaccant
            if (question.equals("") || answer1.equals("") || answer2.equals("") || answer3.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            {
                // Save the Data in Database
                SurveyDataBaseAdapter.insertQuestion(question, answer1, answer2, answer3);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Question Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });


    // try to send home on complete button press
    //*
    //btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
   // btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      //  final Intent intent = new Intent(context, DashHomeActivity.class);
        //
   // });
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

    SurveyDataBaseAdapter.close();
}
}
```

Here is the corresponding XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<LinearLayout style="@style/TitleBar">
    <ImageButton style="@style/TitleBarOperation"
        android:src="@drawable/home_def"
        android:onClick="onHome"
        android:layout_marginTop = "5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom = "5dip"
        android:paddingBottom = "5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_state"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="7dip"/>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/separator"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dip"
        />

    <TextView style="@style/TitleBarText"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextBody"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dip"
        android:text="@string/photoAlbum_detail" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextQuestion"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Question"
         />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextAnswer1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Answer 1"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextAnswer2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Answer 2"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextAnswer3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Answer 3"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:onClick="next"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonComplete"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Complete"
        android:onClick="Complete"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

And upon running my app and hitting the button i get the following error:

```
04-15 21:07:02.622 6642-6642/com.example.david.myview3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.david.myview3, PID: 6642
                                                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method next(View) in the activity class com.example.david.myview3.CreateSurveyActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'buttonNext'
                                                                         at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4013)
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19869)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: next [class android.view.View]
                                                                         at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
                                                                         at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)
                                                                         at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4006)
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785) 
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19869) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Any advice as to what i'm doing wrong when declaring my listener would be great because it works just fine in my other class.

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your xml you have said that it should call the `next` method when the button is clicked:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    android:onClick="next"/> <!-- here -->
```

But you don't have a `next` method declared on your activity.  Just add the method to your activity:

```
public class CreateSurveyActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    public void next(View buttonView) {
        // Whatever should happen when next is clicked.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, with a bit of tinkering i stopped the crash however i dont feel the button is doing anything as it doesnt toast me to say a field is vacant or alternatively say "question created".. is it possible it is not reaching that point in the method?

Comment: @Dave95 Woah, my bad, I didn't notice the whole middle part of your Activity.  I notice two things: 1) you probably don't need to have an onClick in the XML and set an onClickListener programmatically.  My recommendation would be to do it in the XML, because that should be sufficient for your needs.  2) Is createSurvey ever being called?

Comment: Fixed it thanks, yeah i didn't bother creating a new method i just called the createSurvey method which pops a small version of the screen up and allows me to create the question. Thanks for your help!